# XPATH select value of attribute depending on string value

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet where I use the following if-condition to determine the value of an attribute:

```
<xsl:attribute name="newAttr" select="if (@coltype eq 'STRING' or @ColType eq 'INT') then 'True' else 'False'"/>
```

If `@coltype` is `STRING`, it correctly selects `True`, if `@Coltype` is neiher `STRING` nor `INT`, it correctly selects `False`.

However, if `@Coltype` is `INT`, it also selects `False`. How do I write this correctly?

Comment: `coltype` or `ColType` ?

Comment: To complement @Markus comment, beware of the case because XML and XSLT are case-sensitive. `coltype` <> `ColType`.

Comment: Jesus... thanks... sometimes you're just blind.